# R extract categories for points from gridded data

Tags: r, mapping, matching

I have a data frame of locations and I'd been wanting to match them to a categorical variable (climate region) from a map. Here is a small excerpt:

```
df <- data.frame(lat = c(29.30050,  47.67309,  53.30710, -27.60303,  41.31858,  40.50738,  
                         50.67013,60.23163,  42.54555), 
                 long = c(47.806320, -122.315312,   -6.281798,  151.951778,  -72.849961,  
                          -74.382711, 4.348718, 19.710874,  -71.038764))
```

I learned where to get the data from this [excellent article](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_South.pdf). What I want to do is extract the categorical variable for each point set in my data frame. This may sound trivial, but I am new to mapping and can find no help articles. The problem may well be that I'm using the wrong terms!

Mapping the data sets are quite simple with the tutorial, but the grid matching is beyond me. The categorical map data is available in either .txt, .kmz, or GIS format [here](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/present.htm), so I am not limited to one method.

I have tried nearest-matches for each lat and long, but it fails to distinguish which side of the grid to choose from. I have dug through the documentation on pastor, rworldmap, rgdal and all the search combinations I could find on stack overflow.

Comment: are you looking for a spatial overlay? also, can the same data be acquired via ``rworldmap``?

Comment: I didn't see anything in the rworldmap documentation about an internal climate region mapping, although the tutorial link I posted comes from the rworldmap writers. I was able to map the two over each other readily, but not extract the category. alistaire's answer below does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we download the data from the site and read it in as `koeppen`, e.g.

```
download.file('http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/data/Koeppen-Geiger-ASCII.zip', 
              'Koeppen-Geiger-ASCII.zip', 
              method = 'curl')

# use read.table if you like, but read_table cuts a lot of hassle with poor formatting
koeppen <- readr::read_table('Koeppen-Geiger-ASCII.zip')
```

and we look at the data, all the latitudes and longitudes inconveniently end with `.25` or `.75`:

```
koeppen
## # A tibble: 92,416 × 3
##       Lat     Lon   Cls
##     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
## 1  -89.75 -179.75    EF
## 2  -89.75 -179.25    EF
## 3  -89.75 -178.75    EF
## 4  -89.75 -178.25    EF
## 5  -89.75 -177.75    EF
## 6  -89.75 -177.25    EF
## 7  -89.75 -176.75    EF
## 8  -89.75 -176.25    EF
## 9  -89.75 -175.75    EF
## 10 -89.75 -175.25    EF
## # ... with 92,406 more rows
```

Thus, to merge the two tables, we need to round `df`'s latitudes and longitudes to end in `.25` or `.75`, e.g. by

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x){ifelse(x %% 1 > .5, 0.75, 0.25) + floor(x)})
```

gets the remainder from dividing by one, i.e. the non-integer part, and if it's greater than `.5` returns `.75`, else returns `.25`, then re-adding the integer part, so `df` now looks like:

```
df
##      lat    long
## 1  29.25   47.75
## 2  47.75 -122.25
## 3  53.25   -6.25
## 4 -27.75  151.75
## 5  41.25  -72.75
## 6  40.75  -74.25
## 7  50.75    4.25
## 8  60.25   19.75
## 9  42.75  -71.25
```

Now we can use `merge` (or dplyr joins, if you prefer) to add a `Cls` column to `df` for matching latitudes and longitudes:

```
df <- merge(df, koeppen, 
            by.x = c('lat', 'long'), 
            by.y = c('Lat', 'Lon'), 
            all.x = TRUE)

# or dplyr::left_join(df, koeppen, by = c('lat' = 'Lat', 'long' = 'Lon'))

df
##      lat    long Cls
## 1 -27.75  151.75 Cfa
## 2  29.25   47.75 BWh
## 3  40.75  -74.25 Cfa
## 4  41.25  -72.75 Cfa
## 5  42.75  -71.25 Dfb
## 6  47.75 -122.25 Csb
## 7  50.75    4.25 Cfb
## 8  53.25   -6.25 Cfb
## 9  60.25   19.75 Dfb
```

This might also be a good case for [data.table's non-equi-joins](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable), if you like the grammar.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! I was just working at using a 'round_any(df[,1], 0.25, floor)' work around and, of course, just figured out that one of my problems was the 0.25 and 0.75 when I got your response. I'm still working on learning how to use %% modifiers, and this helps me understand better how that works. Thank you so very much!

Comment: `%/%` and `%%` give you the two parts of a long division answer: `%/%`, called integer or floor division, gives you the whole number part; `%%` gives the remainder (also called the modulo), so `7 %/% 3` returns 2 and `7 %% 3` returns 1.